# Android SQL Error Code 1 near ")"

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to write this query in my Android Application with this statement

```
 public void syncflavorcount() {

    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ " SET COUNT = (SELECT SUM(c)" +
            " FROM ("+
            "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv1name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name "+
            " UNION ALL "+
            " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv2name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name "+
            " UNION ALL "+
            " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv3name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name)");
}
```

It complies fine but when it runs I get this error

```
      Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
      Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
      (near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE flavors  SET COUNT = (SELECT SUM(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM recipes WHERE flavors.flv1name = flavors.name  UNION ALL  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recipes WHERE flavors.flv2name = flavors.name  UNION ALL  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recipes WHERE flavors.flv3name = flavors.name))
```

I am not sure why this is. The statement only has 2 open brackets. Can someone check me please. Or help me get this statement working.

The expected output should be that DATABASETABLE2's column name count will be updated with the count of DATABASETABLE's column name flv1name ... flv3name where the entry from flv1name ... flv3name equals DATABASETABLE2's column named name.

```
    DATABASETABLE2

    name    other columns      count
    Apple   ...                1
    Berry   ...                3
    Cherry  ...                0
    ...     ...                ...
```

Comment: the closing bracket of `COUNT = (` is missing at the end

Comment: Thanks that helped with that error but now I have another which seems more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an alias for the inner query

As per @Jens comment, you're also missing a `)` for the open one at `SET COUNT = (`

```
public void syncflavorcount() {
    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ " SET COUNT = (SELECT SUM(c)" +
            " FROM ("+
            "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv1name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name "+
            " UNION ALL "+
            " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv2name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name "+
            " UNION ALL "+
            " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv3name = " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".name) as myTable)");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped with that error but now I have another which seems more complex. '(near "FROM": syntax error (code 1):' with all the FROM's there I assume it is from the first one in the statement.